# How do I assign the result set of a stored procedure to a html table?

Tags: sql, vb.net

I am attempting to search a DB by the last name and have the result set displayed in a table on the page. Unfortunately I don't know how to do this.

Here is the stored procedure

```sql
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.uspSelectPatient
@lName varchar(25)

AS
SELECT lName, fName, patientId, birthday 
FROM dbo.Patients
WHERE lName = @lName
RETURN
```

When the user clicks a button the proc is ran. I think I have every thing accept the display set-up.

```vb
Protected Sub btnSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click
    'Open DB
    Dim objCon As New SqlConnection(mstrCN)
    objCon.Open()

    'Define Command
    Dim objCmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("uspSelectPatient", objCon)
    objCmd.CommandType = Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure

    'Define Data Adapter
    Dim objDataAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter(objCmd)

    'Define Dataset
    Dim objDataSet As New Data.DataSet

    'Fill DataSet
    objDataAdapter.Fill(objDataSet, "Search")

    'Not sure what goes here?

    'Close Objects
    objCmd.Dispose()
    objDataAdapter.Dispose()
    objCon.Close()
    objCon.Dispose()

End Sub
```

Comment: You can fill this using a GridView and binding the DataSet

Comment: It took a lot of fighting, mostly because I do not know the syntax for what I was trying to use but I finally got a GridView to work. The DataSet didn't want to update when I changed the lName value. I finally got it to work by having the default value change when ever the button is clicked.